# How can I create a single raw string from multiple literals in Python?

Tags: python, string, string-literals

I want to combine adjacent strings to a single 'raw' string in Python, e.g.

```
>>> s = (
...     r"foo\tbar\n"
...     "baz\tqux\n")
```

However this only makes the first part 'raw':

```
>>> print(s)
foo\tbar\nbaz   qux

>>>
```

Can I somehow propagate the `'r'` to all adjacent literals?

Answer (score 5):

The `r` prefix is *part of the literal notation*, not part of the resulting string object.

Use it on each line, there is no shortcut here:

```
s = (
    r"foo\tbar\n"
    r"baz\tqux\n")
```

If you really have a lot of these and find all those `r` prefixes that cumbersome, you could use a raw multiline string (triple quoting) and remove the newlines:

```
s = ''.join(r"""
foo\tbar\n
baz\tqux\n
""".splitlines())
```

Note that this won't remove initial whitespace, so you'd either have to start each line at column 0 or use [`textwrap.dedent()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent) to remove consistent leading whitespace for you:

```
from textwrap import dedent

s = ''.join(dedent(r"""
    foo\tbar\n
    baz\tqux\n
""").splitlines())
```

Quick demo:

```
>>> s = (
...     r"foo\tbar\n"
...     r"baz\tqux\n")
>>> s
'foo\\tbar\\nbaz\\tqux\\n'
>>> s = ''.join(r"""
... foo\tbar\n
... baz\tqux\n
... """.splitlines())
>>> s
'foo\\tbar\\nbaz\\tqux\\n'
>>> from textwrap import dedent
>>> s = ''.join(dedent(r"""
...     foo\tbar\n
...     baz\tqux\n
... """).splitlines())
>>> s
'foo\\tbar\\nbaz\\tqux\\n'
```